# Timeout on unit test with TransactionalOperator (Kotlin coroutines)

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a transactional scope like follows ([Spring docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/src/docs/asciidoc/languages/kotlin.adoc#transactions)) and I get it working:

```
class PersonRepository(private val operator: TransactionalOperator) {

    suspend fun initDatabase() = operator.executeAndAwait {
        insertPerson1()
        insertPerson2()
    }
 }
```

But when I try to mock TransactionalOperator in my test like this:

```
val transactionalOperator = mockk<TransactionalOperator>(relaxed = true)
```

I get a timeout every time my test needs the methods that use the operator. Also I haven't found documentation about it.

Does someone have an example of working with tests and mocks on programmatic variant of the Reactive transaction management?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Hope it helps, I used the following construct:

```
val reactiveTransactionManager = mockk<ReactiveTransactionManager>()
val transactionalOperator = TransactionalOperator.create(reactiveTransactionManager)

every { reactiveTransactionManager.getReactiveTransaction(any()) } answers { mono { mockk() } }
every { reactiveTransactionManager.commit(any()) } answers { mono { mockk() } }
every { reactiveTransactionManager.rollback(any()) } answers { mono { mockk() } }
```

Comment: works on my end. thank you sir.

Comment: it works, thx. but if you could add also some explanation, I would appreciate it